# Trying to get a rake task to send an email notification if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rake

My issue is that every time I try to run rake check_pending I get an error. Can someone please help me and let me know what I might be doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is my error

```
rake check_pending
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_all_by_approve_disapprove' for Entry (call 'Entry.connection' to establish a connection):Class
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record /dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
/home/programmer/Test_app/app/models/entry.rb:45:in    `check_pending'
/home/programmer/Test_app/lib/tasks/check_pending.rake:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => check_pending
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This is my model

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.check_pending #This checks if a time off entry is still pending if so then send an email to the manager reminding them of the pending request.
    check_pending = Entry.find_all_by_approve_disapprove('3')
    if approve_disapporve == '3'
       EntryMailer.check_pending(@entry).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

This is my rake task

```
desc "Looks at pending request if the are still marked pending sends a  email to the manager for the request"
task :check_pending => :environment do
Rails.logger.info "Check Pending: Finding all pending."
Entry.check_pending
Rails.logger.info "Found Pending: Check complete."
Rails.logger.flush
end
```

This is my Schedule

```
every :day, :at => "9am" do
rake "check_pending"
end
```

This is my table for entry

```
  ID    NUMBER(38,0)    
  CREATED_AT    DATE        
  UPDATED_AT    DATE    
  APPROVE_DISAPPROVE    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
  EMP_MAIL_ADDR  VARCHAR2 (2555 BYTE)
```

In addition to this question here is my entry_mailer

```
class EntryMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def check_pending(entry)
    @entry = entry

    mail to: entry.emp_mail_addr, subject: '(TEST) You have pending time off request'
  end
end
```

Comment: try `Entry.where(approve_disapprove: '3')` and why 3 is string you can use like this too `Entry.where(approve_disapprove: 3)`

Comment: What you suggested took away that error but now im getting this error ...

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `emp_mail_addr' for Entry (call 'Entry.connection' to establish a connection):Class

Comment: I updated the question with all of the information for this error @Sontya

Comment: `EntryMailer.check_pending(@entry).deliver` in model in this method `@entry` is not there

Comment: I added @entry = entry  to my model for check_pending but im still getting the error NoMethodError: undefined method `emp_mail_addr' for #<Entry::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000006d61180> @Sontya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Entry.where(approve_disapprove: '3')
```

and why 3 is string you can use like this too

```
Entry.where(approve_disapprove: 3)
```

You can loop through all the pending entries and send email to them

```
def self.check_pending
    check_pending = Entry.find_all_by_approve_disapprove(3)
    check_pending.each do |entry|
        EntryMailer.check_pending(entry).deliver
    end 
end
```

Then in your EntryMailer

```
def check_pending(entry)
    @entry = entry
    mail to: @entry.emp_mail_addr, subject: '(TEST) You have pending time off request'
end
```